# Why is the lock activated by XInitThreads non-recursive?

Tags: x11, xlib, xcb

Consider the following call flow:

Function A calls *XCheckIfEvent* passing a pointer to function B in the *predicate* parameter. Function B calls *XGetWindowProperty*.

If XLib is initialized with the *XInitThreads* function, the above call flow hangs at the call to *XGetWindowProperty*. It seems to me that the lock which is activated when *XInitThreads* is called is not recursive. If true, why? Is there a way to make it recursive? Or is it officially prohibited to call XLib functions from within a callback passed to an XLib function?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> If Xlib has been initialized for threads, the predicate is called with
>   the display locked and the result of a call by the predicate to any
>   Xlib function that locks the display is not defined unless the caller
>   has first called *XLockDisplay*.

From the other man page:

> Nested calls to *XLockDisplay* work correctly

So it seems that the predicate must call *XLockDisplay*, and *XUnlockDisplay* when it's done.